# Python: given the pid get the starting time of a user process

Tags: python, windows, process

In continuation of the question title, suppose I have 2 ongoing ftp transfers and I want to selectively kill (in windows using taskkill) the older one. I will get the pids after parsing the output of the tasklist command. I don't know how to distinguish between them based on starting time - when the user initiated them in the past. Can this be done in python.

What I know is that the pids can be random that is the newer process may have a smaller/larger pid than the older one. So starting time has to be seen.

Please help

Answer (score 7):

You can do that with [psutils](http://code.google.com/p/psutil/wiki/Documentation):

Directly from the documentation:

```
>>> import os, psutil, datetime
>>> p = psutil.Process(os.getpid())
>>> p.create_time
1307289803.47
>>> datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(p.create_time).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
'2011-03-05 18:03'
```

Comment: Note: Since this answer, `create_time` [is now a method](http://pythonhosted.org/psutil/#psutil.Process.create_time) -- e.g. `p.create_time()`